# Picasa with how to know album id and user id?

Tags: api, picasa

I have got picasa hot-link like this.

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=ddd4d19a3f2920752&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1411973660&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=A4C2BADEBFC590D4DEF3349AE2F849B91F1CF0FE.9797B66270D813953D04F061BE68B963F03528FD&key=lh1
```

and I have an expire date !

```
expire=1411973660
```

and when I convert to time is that expire on

```
Mon, 29 Sep 2014 06:54:20 GMT
```

That mean at 30 Sep 2014 I can't view the video with this hot-link right?

So question is how can I find the real userid albumid from the picasa id like

```
id=ddd4d19a3f2920752
```

or is there have a way to create a new expire date?

Thanks you for help.